# Render a c program into a html using python

Tags: python, jinja2

**Task is to render a c program into an HTML file using python**

this is my code

```
from jinja2 import Template

html_template = '''
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>
            {% for i in code %}  {{i}}<br> {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </body> 
    </html>'''

# reading c program file
file_content = open("prog.c",'r').readlines()
template = Template(html_template)
html_content = template.render(code = file_content)

with open('outp.html','w') as f:
    f.write(html_content)
```

consider the prog.c file contains

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    }
```

The HTML output should be

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) {
        printf("Hello World!");
        }
```

but what I get is

```
    #include
    int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    }
```

I have two problems in doing this:

1. The indentation before 'printf...' line should also reflect in HTML.
2. The `<stdio.h>` in c code is considered as HTML tag while rendering, I need it as text in html.

Note: Constraints

1. should not change the prog.c file since it will always be dynamic.

you can use python string formatting or jinja templating that is up to you, I just need a solution.

Can you please suggest me some idea?

Comment: use `<pre>` tag maybe? That should keep the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the `django.template` to achieve it

(I like `django-template` style. But don't worry. It styles pretty similarly to the `jinja`)

```
from django.template import Template, Engine, Context

file_content = '''
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    }
'''

html_template = '''
    <html>
        <body>
            <pre>{% for i in code %}{{i}}<br>{% endfor %}</pre>
        </body> 
    </html>'''

t = Template(html_template, engine=Engine())
result = t.render(Context(dict(code=[_ for _ in file_content.split('\n') if _ != ''])))
result_compress = ''.join([_.strip() for _ in result.split('\n') if _.strip()])
with open('outp_compress.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result_compress)
print(result_compress)
with open('outp.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result)
print(result)
```

## View in browser

Opening in the browser looks like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    }
```

## TextContent

### outp_compress.html

```
<html><body><pre>#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;<br>int main(void) {<br>    printf(&quot;Hello World!&quot;);<br>    }<br></pre></body></html>
```

### outp.html

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <pre>#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;<br>int main(void) {<br>    printf(&quot;Hello World!&quot;);<br>    }<br></pre>
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you @carson. This is the solution I need.
How did you know about this thing in Django template?
I haven't noted it when I was trying it.
Thank you for your reply!.

Comment: It's a long story, I will respond to you a few days.
TLDR, I read the Django-template source code.